# Erreur lors de l'envoi de l'email (SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase)

Tags: email, smtp, redmine

I'm using Redmine 2.6.4.stable, with Ruby version 1.9.3-p194 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux], and Rails version 3.2.21.
**I can't activate the sending by email.**
I catch that error : "Erreur lors de l'envoi de l'email (SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase)".
I check my config in the config/configuration.yml every thing look ok :

```
    production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: smtp.google.com
      port: 25
      domain: mydomain.com
      user_name: redmine@mydomain.com
```

Every one migth have meet that kind of problem ? Thanks to please tell me how I could solve it.

Best regards,
Djass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Are your credentials really right?

If yes have a look at [Open Project Configuration of E-Mail-Notification - Error (SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase)](https://community.openproject.org/topics/1385)

There the opener could resolve his issue doing (of course you have to set your credentials / server infos):

```
email_delivery_method: :confounded:mtp #main level, will not work

default: #main level
email_delivery_method: :confounded:mtp #setting for default
smtp_address: smtp.server.com #setting for default
smtp_port: 587
smtp_domain: my-domain.com
smtp_user_name: username
smtp_password: pass
smtp_enable_starttls_auto: true
smtp_authentication: plain
```

and then had to restart is apache server

> and than i have to restart the apache-server. I do not know for now if the passenger-modul or ruby re-read the yml-files after changeing them or the fcgi-modul. Nevertheless it works.

edit: This is my email configuration working smoothly

```
email_delivery:
delivery_method: :smtp
smtp_settings:
enable_starttls_auto: false
address: "host_in_double_question"
port: 587
domain: 'domain_of_mailserver_in_single_quotes'
authentication: :login
user_name: "username_in_double_questions"
password: "password_in_double_quotes"
openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
```